# Counting with AJAX and Laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a system where users can say they have visited a place. I am trying to get the number of visits to +1 if the person visits a place and -1 if they unvisit the place. the number changes if i refresh a page but i want it to change live with AJAX. Here is the code i have so far:

HTML:

```
            @if($place->visitors->count() == 1)
                <h5 class="visitor-count count">{{ $place->visitors->count()}} person has visited this place</h5>
            @else
                <h5 class="visitor-count count">{{ $place->visitors->count()}} people have visited this place</h5>
            @endif
```

Ajax JS:

```
$('.visit').on('click', function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
// Make the button a variable here
var buttonToChange = $(this);
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: urlVisit,
    data: {
        place_id: $(event.target).data("id"),
        _token: token
    },
    success: function(){
    // Change the button here
        if(buttonToChange.hasClass('btn-visited')){
            buttonToChange.addClass('btn-not-visited');
            buttonToChange.removeClass('btn-visited');
            buttonToChange.html('Not Visited');
        //Count will go down
        }
        else{
            // Do the opposite
            buttonToChange.addClass('btn-visited');
            buttonToChange.removeClass('btn-not-visited');
            buttonToChange.html('Visited');
//count will go up
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How do i edit the current code so that the count is live and will update on click rather than refresh

Comment: @detinu20, Are you possibly going to mark my other answer as correct?

Comment: i did>? any ideas on the count?

Comment: do you want to save that count state in database?

Comment: No. Not saving just updating